# How to do group_concat on two fields in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, group-concat

My `cities` table:

```
year | id | city
2005   10   LA
2005   11   SF
2007   12   NY
2008   13   NO
```

with the query:

```
SELECT year, GROUP_CONCAT(id) 
FROM cities 
GROUP BY year
```

I get the output:

```
2005|10,11
2007|12
2008|13
```

But what I would like to get is something like (for example):

```
2005|10,LA,11,SF
2007|12,NY
2008|13,NO
```

In other words I would like both the id and the name in the result, grouped by year, and not just the id. How does one do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#group_concat) takes 2 arguments: the expression to be aggregated and the separator (the default separator is `,`).
In your case, you need multiple columns for the expression part so you must build it by concatenation:

```
SELECT year, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(id || ',' || city) AS id_city
FROM cities
GROUP BY year;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f596b23ef36aeb85b4ba53d23812dc9a).